# Is $f(z)=\sum_{m=1}^{+\infty} z^m/m^{1/3}$ continuous at $-1$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$f$ can be defined on the interval $[-1,1)$ and is continuous on $(-1,1)$. I was wondering if $f$ is also continuous at $-1$. Any ideas?

Comment: Please declare the domain of definition for $f$, it is else hard to guess...

Comment: @dan_fulea I edited my question.

Comment: Abel's test for power series in complex analysis :: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test#Abel's_test_in_complex_analysis does the job...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES.

This is due to [Abel's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem).

In particular, $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{m^{1/3}}$ converges, and hence, according to Abel's Theorem
$$
\lim_{x\to -1^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 1^-} \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^n}{m^{1/3}}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{m^{1/3}}=f(-1).
$$

Comment: Do you know what happens if we approximate $-1$ from the unit disk?

Comment: That could take a lot of work to determine. I can't predict the answer. There exists counterexamples, where the function is not continuous.